# How do I make an API call to viralheat on submit and then parse and save the JSON response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, api, sentiment-analysis

I want to send a request via Viralheat's API in my controller's update method so that when a user hits the submit button, an action is completed and the API call is made. I want to post to http://www.viralheat.com/api/sentiment/review.json?text=i&do&not&like&this&api_key=[*** your api key ***]

This will return some JSON in the format:

```
{"mood":"negative","prob":0.773171679917001,"text":"i do not like this"}
```

Is it possible to make that API call simultaneously while executing the controller method and how would I handle the JSON response? Which controller method would I put it in?

Ultimately I'd like to save the response mood to my sentiment column in a BrandUsers table. Submit is in main.html.erb which then uses the update method.

**Controller**

```
def update
  @brand = Brand.find(params[:id])
  current_user.tag(@brand, :with => params[:brand][:tag_list], :on => :tags)
  if @brand.update_attributes(params[:brand])
    redirect_to :root, :notice  => "Brand tagged."
  else
    render :action => 'edit'
  end
end

def main
  @brands = Brand.all
  if current_user
    @brand = current_user.brands.not_tagged_by_user(current_user).order("RANDOM()").first
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `wrest` gem installed, you could do something like

```
params[:api_key] = "your key"

url = "http://www.viralheat.com/api/sentiment/review.json"

response = url.to_uri.get(params).deserialize
```

`response` would contain the json already turned into a hash. So you can access the mood with

```
response[:mood]
```

Comment: I tried that in http://wrestdemo.heroku.com/ and it doesn't recognize deserialize. Think I'll just go with `HTTPARTY` instead.

Comment: Have you tried actually installing it? The demo app might be a bit wonky.

Comment: Just inspect the response object. Maybe the server answer is different from what you expect.